# Pattern Matching for rules parameter Gitlab CI

Tags: regex, gitlab-ci

I am trying to make use of the rules: parameter to make a job only appear in a pipeline if specified users did the push. I dont want to define the list of users for each job, so I have the following global variable:

```
variables:
  USER_LIST: "user1 user2 user3"
```

and in the job, I have the following:

```
rules:
 - if '$USER_LIST =~ /$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN/'
    when: on_success
 - when: never
```

This does not appear to be working, as I suspect the regex pattern being used is not being replaced by the variable, and using `$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN` as the search string. If I use an explicit search:

```
rules:
 - if '$USER_LIST =~ /user1/'
    when: on_success
 - when: never
```

then the pattern matches just fine.

NOTE: I am aware that `GITLAB_USER_LOGIN` is a protected variable. I get the same problem with `GITLAB_USER_EMAIL` too.

So the question is, how can I put a GITLAB predifined variable into a string that will be used for pattern matching?

Comment: There is an open issue in GitLab with pattern matching against a variable. Could be related to that. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35438

Comment: Thanks - I found that a while ago (after this post) - shame I have to use literals! :(

Comment: @TheLoneKing That issue was closed as a duplicate. Status will be tracked here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/209904.

Answer (score 7):

We can't use variables inside pattern for some (gitlab) reason. But we can swap list of privileged users and the current user in rule. Just transform list of users to regexp pattern:

```
.job:
    variables: 
        PRIVILEGED_USERS_PATTERN: '/user1|user2|userN/i'
    rules:
        - if: $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN =~ $PRIVILEGED_USERS_PATTERN
          when: manual
```

This solution has two minuses:

1. List of privileged users visible to all, who have reading access to the project
2. Pattern length limit (no testing)

But for now i don't see other solution how to not running the job at all.

Comment: Man, this saved my life .. kinda. Wasted 5 hours already, but swapping actually did the trick. What the hell ...

Answer (score 3):

You are using a variable and not a regular expression in your rule. So you don't need the slashes around the `$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN` variable. Try something like this:

```
rules:
  - if '$USER_LIST =~ $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN'
```

Comment: but this syntax cannot be used together with logical operators, such as `'$a = $b' && '$c = $d'`.

Answer (score 2):

In our case, we wanted to run the job only if the current branch matched a list of specific branches.

We created a project level variable named PROTECTED_BRANCHES_REGEX with the value

```
/^develop$|^release-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[1,2]$|^hotfixes-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[1,2].[0,1]$|^master$/
```

Then we defined the following rule in the job:

```
rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ $PROTECTED_BRANCHES_REGEX
```

That works fine with Gitlab version 15.4.6-ee.

Answer (score 1):

I have more or less the same problem setup. The issues mentioned in the comments were addressed in 15.1, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#store-the-regex-pattern-in-a-variable.

Nevertheless `'$USER_LIST =~ /$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN/'` still doesn't work. Also, if you define a variable like `pattern: /$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN/` and use that in the way described in the documentation, it doesn't work.

`'$USER_LIST =~ $pattern'`

What works, but isn't the solution to your or my problem is defining pattern with a fixed pattern, like `pattern: /user1/`. Then it works if used like this:

`'$USER_LIST =~ $pattern'`

But obviously, I want to use the actual user, that tries to create a pipeline.

What works on my instance (15.4) is this:

`'$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN =~ $USER_LIST'`

I have no idea why, cos in my opinion this is no behaviour suggested by the documentation. I looked around in several places and found no documented examples of this use, but it works.

This job gets created with a delayed start:

```
variables:
  pattern: "user"
  string: "this contains user and other stuff"

show-env:
  stage: env
  tags:
    - ops
  rules:
    - if: $pattern =~ $string
      when: delayed
      start_in: 15m
    - when: always
  script:
    - env
```

And if you remove `user` from string and push it again, it gets executed right away.

And it also works when I define `USERLIST` in the project ci/cd variables and test that against `$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN`.

Comment: We are having the same problem here. We thought 15.1 will fix the issue but unfortunately, it doesn't. Is there a bug issue for this?

Comment: There is at least one, which is mentioned in the original questions comments.

Comment: The reason why the `$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN =~ $USER_LIST` works, is because the improperly formatted RE2 regular expression falls back to checking whether the string to the left of the `=~` operator is a subset of the string to its right (e.g. if `$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN` is a subset of `$USER_LIST`. See more here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#compare-a-variable-to-a-regex-pattern

Comment: Excerpt of the above: _When using the =~ character, make sure the right side of the comparison always contains a valid regular expression. If the right side of the comparison is not a valid regular expression enclosed with / characters, the expression evaluates in an unexpected way. In that case, the comparison checks if the left side is a substring of the right side. For example, "23" =~ "1234" evaluates to true, which is the opposite of "23" =~ /1234/, which evaluates to false. You should not configure your pipeline to rely on this behavior._

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#supported-syntax) shows that the content matching regex should look like this:

`$VARIABLE =~ /^content.*/`

for your code you need to add `^` and `.*`:

```
rules:
 - if '$USER_LIST =~ /^user1.*/'
    when: on_success
 - when: never
```

Comment: It works with the string values, but he needs to use variable in regex, any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to build an [dynamic-child-pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines) where the variable within pattern already evaluated and inserted as constant string.