# Run a Gitlab CI job if its name is in a variable

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I was trying to execute a Gitlab CI job if its name is in a variable.
I don't want to hardcode the job name inside the if condition.

```
rules:
  - if: '$JOBS =~ /\b$CI_JOB_NAME\b/'
```

This approach seems clean and efficient.
Unfortunately, the rule is not matched, and the job is not executed.

I also tried the following code, and it works.
So, I suppose the problem is related to the regex. The limit of the solution below is that it doesn't allow to specify multiple jobs.

```
rules:
  - if: '$JOBS == $CI_JOB_NAME'
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve as this seems like an XY problem.  you say you want to run a job if some variable matches the job name but for what purpose. are you trying to be able to run particular jobs based on user input? In your current solution the CI_JOB_NAME wont be populated till the job runs but the job wont run unless the rules is evaluated as true so its catch 22

Comment: This is not true because the condition `if: '$JOBS == $CI_JOB_NAME'` works.

Comment: ah ok well thats a lesson learned for me. What is an example job name and value for JOBS thats not working when you use the expression match.

Comment: The only other thing I could find is this statement in the gitlab docs `Variables on the right side of =~ and !~ expressions are evaluated as regular expressions. The regular expression must be enclosed in forward slashes (/)` I have tried many flavours and your regex is fine when you replace the variable with the real text it works. It also works if you put it in variable like `my_job_expression: /\bmytest2\b/` and then have the rule like `- if: '$myvar =~ $my_job_expression'` but I cant see a way to directly put the var in the regex at the rule level. will keep an eye on this to see updates

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. We can't use variables inside a pattern. There are possible solutions:
[Pattern Matching for rules parameter Gitlab CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60653421/pattern-matching-for-rules-parameter-gitlab-ci)